# how to save two data on one cell Date and time

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, datetime-format, sqlyog

i have two Datetimepicker. One is formatted as Date, and the other one is formatted as Time. Now i have database which have 3 columns: ID, Name, and Schedule.
I want to save the date and time in the schedule column formatted like this **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM**

What datatype should i use in schedule column?

Comment: DateTime values should always be saved to ... DateTime columns,  It is not clear if you also want to save the Date separate from the Time.  Neither the DateTime var nor a DateTime dbcol have a format though.  If you save them together there is no reason to make the user pick them individually is there?

Comment: no. i want to save date + time in one cell in the column schedule using datetimepicker :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining (concatenating) date and time into a datetime

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
     string one = "13/02/09";
     string two = "2:35:10 PM";

     DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(one + " " + two);
     DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(one + " " + two, "dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss    tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Console.WriteLine(dt1);
    }
}
```